# Multiple Lines and Bars in Plotly Axis

Tags: r, graph, plotly

I am trying to plot 3 time series, one of them are values in millions and are to be plotted as bar chart, the other 2 are % values using `plotly`. The code for the same is as written using a function and 3 traces have been added. 
I think the primary problem is with respect to the layout specifications. 
the layout code is:

```
layout(title="Prepayment Trend",
           xaxis=list(title='Time Period', showgrid=T, zeroline=T, zerolinecolor="e8e8e8"),
           yaxis=list(title='Millions',showgrid=F, zeroline=F, zerolinecolor="e8e8e8", ticks=""),
           yaxis2=list(title='Percentage ', ticks="inside",showgrid=F, zeroline=F, zerolinecolor="e8e8e8",
                       tickmode="linear",tick0=0,dtick=0.005,tickformat='',
                       overlaying = "y",side = "right"))
```

Herein the problem is that the 0 value of the secondary y axis is being displayed higher than the Y axis 0 value; as can be seen in the graph below:

[image]

Can someone please help me overcome this problem so that the graph finally looks something like the one below:

[image]

the data for the same is as follows:
Time    PrepayAmount    SMM M1SAIBOR
1-Feb-12    105 3.5%    0.5%
1-May-12    75  2.4%    0.5%
1-Aug-12    64  1.5%    0.5%
1-Nov-12    64  2.0%    0.5%
1-Feb-13    86  2.0%    0.5%
1-May-13    87  1.2%    0.5%
1-Aug-13    131 2.6%    0.5%
1-Nov-13    150 1.3%    0.5%
1-Feb-14    76  1.5%    0.5%
1-May-14    40  1.9%    0.5%
1-Aug-14    146 0.5%    0.5%
1-Nov-14    142 1.2%    0.5%
1-Feb-15    68  2.5%    0.5%
1-May-15    116 2.0%    0.5%
1-Aug-15    144 3.0%    0.5%
1-Nov-15    89  1.0%    0.5%
1-Feb-16    65  1.2%    1.0%
1-May-16    154 2.5%    1.3%
1-Aug-16    167 1.2%    1.5%
1-Nov-16    142 2.5%    2.0%
1-Feb-17    104 0.0%    1.8%
1-May-17    77  1.0%    1.6%
1-Aug-17    96  2.5%    1.5%

Comment: please click on the links for the images.

Comment: a reproducible example would help...

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Your chances of getting an answer are much higher if you provide a [MCVE].